# Eclipse and Package Explorer

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to set up a new Eclipse project with a directory structure as follows:

```
Myproject/
    src/
        config/
        java/
    test/
        config/
        java/
    lib
```

Where `src/` and `test/` are both "source" folders (they contain either .xml or .java files). Obviously, `src/config/` contains all the XML config files for my primary Java source files (which get packaged under `src/java/`).

What I'd like to achieve (if possible) would be to just see the following in Package Explorer:

```
MyProject
    src/config
    src/java
    test/config
    test/java
    lib
```

But instead, after adding all fource "source" folders to the project, I see this:

```
MyProject
    src
    src/config
    src/java
    test
    test/config
    test/java
    lib
```

This is **most annoying**!! When I go into Project Properties >> Java Build Path >> Source I see the same folders listed as source folders as directly above:

```
MyProject/src
MyProject/src/config
MyProject/src/java
MyProject/test
MyProject/test/config
MyProject/test/java
```

Is there any way to *force* Package Explorer to present my 4 source folders and **not** even list the `src/` and `test/` folders? It just seems bulky, unnecessary and annoying, since I'll never be adding anything to them directly. Everything will be added to their `config/` and `java/` subdirectories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Navigator view instead of the Package view.  It provides a hierarchical view of your project instead of showing every package at the same level.

Comment: Or click on the little triangle at the top right of the package explorer, and choose "Package presentation - Hierarchical"

Comment: It turns out that Eclipse v4.1 has dropped the Navigator view.  The "Package presentation -> Hierarchical" choice for the Package Explorer is now the only way to get this behavior.

Answer (score 3):

`src` and `test` should not be source folders. `src/java`, `src/config`, `test/java`, `test/config` should be source folders. Source folders should contain the root of the package tree. And java and config are not packages.

Comment: JB - exactly! That's my question! How can I de-source the src/ and test/ folders, but keep their subdirectories as sources?

Comment: Project - Properties - Java Build Path - Sources - Remove

Answer (score 1):

I would only set src/ and test/ as source folders. You can put packages / folders there for structure.